How to Access localhost on mobile
I am building a web application using Laravel for APIs and React for the frontend . I want to test the app on a mobile phone. I usually test React alone, and it works, but the information from the backend is not working (authentication, CRUD, etc.). Can I access it? I run React using npm run dev -- --host and Laravel using php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000, but nothing is displaying except the static data.

look into ngrok

localhost is a hostname for 127.0.0.1 and that is the loopback address. It makes no sense to access localhost from your mobile device.

Try this:

Run ipconfig
Grab your IPv4
Run php artisan serve --host=<yourIPv4>
In your React code change the API request URL to your server's address, probably http://<yourIPv4>:8000

Note: of course your phone and your serve must be connected to the same network

I solve this problem.
in the backend run php artisan serve 0.0.0.0
in react run npm run dev -- --host
in the terminal run ipconfig  get the ipadress and replace it in the request
for example the request will be axiocClient.get(http://YourIpaddress:8000/whatever)

You can try this. Find the local IP of your PC running the localhost, then append the port to that IP when on your phone i.e. 192.168.1.5:3000.
Another solution is to use ngrok which is super easy to get running.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
